# Maven run issue in spring tool suite for spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am getting the below error on executing springboot:run in Spring tool suite for a spring boot application.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 9.020 s
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/262M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project documentupload-svc: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please suggest how to resolve the issue in Spring tool suite.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a windows machine:

1) set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the folder where your java is.

2) set M2_HOME environment variable to the folder where maven is.

3) add %JAVA_HOME%/bin:%M2_HOME%/bin to the start of your PATH environment variable.

4) make sure your STS has a JDK set.